# "do not have to" vs. "must not"

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, negation

> I do not have to wait for bus.

Which one does it mean?

- I am under obligation (e.g. to leave the bus station and go and) not to wait for the bus.
- I am under no obligation to wait for bus and I am free to choose waiting or not.

If the answer is the first, then it will be equal to

> I must not wait for bus.

and if not it means that "must" and "have to" are similar in positive meaning but different after negation.

Comment: If you read the answer of @StoneyB to the question you linked to, you would have learned that **have to** is really one word (or one lexical unit)  and it expresses obligation. So your first sentence still means 'I am under no obligation to wait for the bus (and I am free to choose whether to wait or not)'. I hope that helps.

Comment: In addition, 'I **have to** do something' expresses external obligation. (I have to go to work, but I don't want to).  And 'I **need** to do something' expresses internal obligation or compulsion. (basically, I need to and I want to).

Comment: @δοῦλος Of course I know and knew that 'have to' is not a normal auxiliary verb and I also deal with it like a one-word verb (like 'must' which is a one-word obligation auxiliary verb). But the point is: like 'must not', "do not have to" doesn't seem to have the second sentence meaning.

Comment: Trust me, it means the second! Let's try this again: *I do not have to* equals *I am under no obligation or compulsion to*. Therefore you simply substitute *I am under no obligation to* for *I do not have to* in your first sentence. The result is '*I am under no obligation to* wait for the bus.' (Therefore, I am free to walk away and take the train or a taxi or walk or swim...)

Comment: *I must not wait for the bus* means *I am under obligation to not wait for the bus.* To express this with *have to*, it would be the unusual *I have to not wait for the bus.* (I must leave here.)

Comment: @δοῦλος Thanks; you can write the meaning of both, as an answer to be accepted; But you do not have to!

Comment: So *must not* means *have to not*. But we say *must not* much more often than *have to not*. We rarely say *have to not*. And *have to not* is not the same as *not have to/don't have to*. So, *must* is the opposite of *don't have to*. Thus, *You must wait* = *You have to wait.* But *You must not wait* does not equal *You don't have to wait*, but *You "have to" not wait*.

Comment: Thanks @hossanyi, but I have to go. :)  I just hope I helped.

Comment: @δοῦλος You are welcome. However, the edit in my question didn't mean a new question; I just wanted to make it prepared for your answer. Have a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In view of the comments, it's the second sentence (I am not forced to wait for a bus) that is near in meaning to the sentence "I don't have to wait for a bus".

Answer (score 1):

> I do not have to wait for a bus.

Without additional context, this sentence could mean any of the following things:

I have a car. I don't have to take the bus.

The bus is reliable and arrives frequently. I don't have to wait and wait and wait for it to arrive.

I can leave this bus stop at any time. No one is forcing me to be here.